# r expand dataset with filled in data

Tags: r, dplyr, apply, reshape

I have a dataset with 4 columns. This can take 2 values for now.(1 or 0). There are three columns (X1, X2, X3) with missing data.

```
Row#    X1   X2   X3    Y
1       1    0    0     1
2       0    1    1     0 
3       NA   0    0     0
4       1    1    1     0
5       1    NA   NA    1
6       1    0    0     1
7       NA   NA   NA    0
8       0    1    0     1
9       NA   NA   1     0
10      0    0    1     1
11      NA   NA   0     0
12      0    0    0     0
13      0    0    1     1
14      NA   0    NA    0
```

What i am interested in creating an filled in dataset for possible values of NA. What i mean by this is creating possible rows of data like this below

```
Row#   X1  X2  X3  Y  Probability  Comments
1      1   0   0   1  1            No missing
2      0   1   1   0  1            No missing

3      1   0   0   0  0.5          X1 Missing
4      0   0   0   0  0.5          X1 Missing

5      1   1   1   0  1            No missing

6      1   1   0   1  0.25         X1, X2 missing 
7      1   0   0   1  0.25         X1, X2 missing 
8      1   1   1   1  0.25         X1, X2 missing 
9      1   0   1   1  0.25         X1, X2 missing 

10     1   0   0   1  1            No missing 

11     0   0   0   0  0.125        X1, X2, x3 missing 
12     1   0   0   0  0.125        X1, X2, x3 missing
13     0   1   0   0  0.125        X1, X2, x3 missing
14     0   0   1   0  0.125        X1, X2, x3 missing
15     1   1   0   0  0.125        X1, X2, x3 missing
16     1   0   1   0  0.125        X1, X2, x3 missing
17     0   1   1   0  0.125        X1, X2, x3 missing
18     1   1   1   0  0.125        X1, X2, x3 missing
19     .   .   .   .  .            ......
20     .   .   .   .  .            ......
21     .   .   .   .  .            ......
22     .   .   .   .  .            ......
```

Please note the final dataset will contain 5 columns (X1,X2,X3,Y,Possibility)

The column `Probability` is calculated based on this logic.

- Let us start with Row1&2 in 1st dataset . The first two rows(1,2) dont have any missing data so in the expected output the same two rows are generated and the probability is 1.
- Let us look at Row3 in the original dataset. This has missing value in column X1. So two rows 3,4 are generated in the expected output. Hence probability 0.5, 0.5. `1/2=0.5`
- Let us look at the 5th rows in the original dataset. This contains missing data in column X2 and X3. So this will generate 4 rows in Expected data, row# 6,7,8.9. So probability is 0.25, 0.25,0.25, 0.25, `1/4 = 0.25`
- Row7 of the original dataset has missing values for x1,x2,x3. So this scenario will generate 8 rows, row 11- row 18 in the expected output dataset. Hence the probability 0.125 , `1/8 = 0.125`

I could do this using 8 ifelse statements and for loops. But I am wondering if there is any esier and less messy way to achieve this. Thanks.

Comment: @akrun, this depends on the number of missing values per row. For example a row with one missing value will generate two rows in the expected dataset. A row with 2 missing values will generate 4 rows in the expected dataset and a row with all missing values will generate 8 rows in the expected dataset ? Does this answer your question ?

Comment: @akrun, ah, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: How do you compute the Possibility `col`?

Comment: @VíctorCortés, good question. I have updated my question with description explaining how the probabilities are estimated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I defined a function for combinations of `{0,1}` for any numbers using `expand.grid`. For `n` equal to `0`, I used a data.frame with 1 dimension to avoid complications for rows without `NA`.

```
comb <- function(n) { 
    if(n==0) return(data.frame(Var1 = c(1)))
    expand.grid(rep(list(0:1),n)) 
}
```

Now I am using apply and replace function to create list of rows. I have used `mutate` from `dplyr` to create probability column.

```
df = apply(df, 1, function(v){
  NA_count = length(which(is.na(v)))
  apply(comb(NA_count) , 1 ,  FUN = replace , x = v, list = 
  which(is.na(v))) %>% 
  t %>% as.data.frame() %>%
  mutate( Probability = (1/2)^length(which(is.na(v))))
})
```

Finally, I put all the lists together with `do.call`.

```
do.call(rbind,df)
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be simplified - but let me know if this is closer to what you need.

There are 2 functions here:

- One function `make_mat(x, k)` creates a vector containing 0 and 1 (e.g., `make_mat(7,4)` is `0 1 1 1` which is 4 bits long and the binary is equal to 7)
- The second function `sub_mat` will create a matrix of `2^n_repl` rows, where `n_repl` is the number of `NA` to replace.

A list is created for each row in the original data frame. Right now, the number of rows `num_row` is computed for the list, and the `probability` is set to `1/num_row`.

```
make_mat <- function(x, k) {
  return(rev(as.integer(intToBits(x))[1:k]))
}

sub_mat <- function(x) {
  n_repl <- sum(+(is.na(x)))
  mat_repl <- t(sapply(1:2^n_repl-1, make_mat, k = n_repl))
  new_mat <- matrix(rep(x, 2^n_repl), ncol = length(x), byrow = T)
  new_mat[is.na(new_mat)] <- mat_repl
  new_mat
}

lst <- apply(df, 1, sub_mat)
num_row <- sapply(lst, nrow, simplify = T)
result <- as.data.frame(Reduce(rbind, Map(cbind, lst, 1/num_row)))
names(result) <- c(names(df), "probability")
result
```

**Output**

```
   X1 X2 X3 Y probability
1   1  0  0 1       1.000
2   0  1  1 0       1.000
3   0  0  0 0       0.500
4   1  0  0 0       0.500
5   1  1  1 0       1.000
6   1  0  0 1       0.250
7   1  0  1 1       0.250
8   1  1  0 1       0.250
9   1  1  1 1       0.250
10  1  0  0 1       1.000
11  0  0  0 0       0.125
12  0  0  1 0       0.125
13  0  1  0 0       0.125
14  0  1  1 0       0.125
15  1  0  0 0       0.125
16  1  0  1 0       0.125
17  1  1  0 0       0.125
18  1  1  1 0       0.125
19  0  1  0 1       1.000
20  0  0  1 0       0.250
21  0  1  1 0       0.250
22  1  0  1 0       0.250
23  1  1  1 0       0.250
24  0  0  1 1       1.000
25  0  0  0 0       0.250
26  0  1  0 0       0.250
27  1  0  0 0       0.250
28  1  1  0 0       0.250
29  0  0  0 0       1.000
30  0  0  1 1       1.000
31  0  0  0 0       0.250
32  0  0  1 0       0.250
33  1  0  0 0       0.250
34  1  0  1 0       0.250
```

Comment: thanks Ben. I will test this logic with different test cases